# How to fix below warning message while deploying module using wildfly22

Tags: spring-boot, maven, jboss7.x, wildfly-22

> warn-Failed to define class  org.springframework.web.servlet.tags . form. AbstractHtmlElementTag in             Module "deployment. .war" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/form/AbstractHtmlElementTag (Module "deployment. .war" from Service Module Loader): jakarta/servlet/jsp/tagext/DynamicAttributes

I am trying to upgrade from springboot 2.5.x to 3.0.0 and while deploying the module using wildfly 22(eclipse server),i am getting above warning messages in eclipse console.

**I am using-**

```
eclipse 2021-09
java 17.0.5
wildfly 22
springboot-starter-parent-3.0.0
spring. Framework.version-6.0.2
jakarta.servlet-api-6.0.0 
jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-3.0.0
jakarta.servlet.jsp-api-3.1.1
```

**I tried-**

- Checking the compatibility between the dependencies- spring-webmvc-6.0.2 (AbstractHtmlElementTag is from this dependency or jar ) and jakarta.servlet.jsp-api-3.1.1(DynamicAttributes.class is from this dependency or jar).
- I even tried to check whether there is any Dependency conflict.
- I tried deleting the JAR file from local Maven repository and re-downloading it.

Yet the issue isn't resolved.

Answer (score 0):

WildFly 22 is a Jakarta EE 8 container. Spring Boot 3 requires Jakarta EE 9 or higher. You'd need to use WildFly 27+ to get Jakarta EE 10 support.